# Deploying AngularJS / Javascript applications

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, deployment

We use **grunt build** to build an angularJS application.

After the built application is published on the live server, how to let users know that there is a new version of the **JS** application available? Because their browser will still have the previous combined javascript file.

Also the backend, which is **PHP (Symfony2)** might change, so if user doesn't refresh the page, some API calls might not work. Keep in mind that the backend changes will be very rare. Versioning the *API* as *v1, v2*... might be a small solution, but in the long run everyone would end up using the newest API, so keeping the old versions is not required for longer period of time.

I was thinking to make use of **Angular's** `$interval` service and make a checker every minute to a simple web service, which would return the version number of the new application. If version is newer, angular should display a message and let user know to refresh the page or force refresh it. Is that a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add a unique version_id to the file itself using grunt.

```
src="name_of_your_file.js?v=INCREASING_VERSION_NUMBER"
```

e.g

```
src="name_of_your_file.js?v=2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not really what I needed at that time. With Angular you try to build single page sites, so users do not refresh the page that often, so this solution would not be that efficient.

Comment: Lets take for example Spotify of Popcorn time.
When they have an update they ask you to restart the app.
That way they can use the version method I've described above.